# Optional Permissions are not being applied after being added

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I am adding `nativeMessaging` permission to my Browser Extension with the following code:

```js
// function triggered by user gesture
const promptPermissionsUpgrade = () =>
  new Promise((res) =>
    chrome.permissions.request({ permissions: ['nativeMessaging'] }, res)
```

Then listening for the upgrade:

```js
chrome.permissions.onAdded.addListener(({permissions}) => {
  if (permissions && permissions.includes("nativeMessaging")) {
    connectNative();
  }
});
```

When I call `connectNative()`, I run `chrome.runtime.connectNative('app_name')`.
This throws `TypeError: chrome.runtime.connectNative is not a function`.

I double checked the key in my `manifest.json` and it is correct (`"optional_permissions": ["nativeMessaging"]`).

The example in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/permissions/request#examples) does not say anything about this.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The app would work as expected on reload, so I realized I could just have the extension reload and voila! It worked as expected.

```js
!chrome.runtime.connectNative && chrome.runtime.reload();
chrome.runtime.connectNative('app_name')
```

-- [`runtime.reload` docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-reload)